# Infinite scrolling bad for SEO

Tags: javascript, html, seo

Is infinite scrolling bad for SEO since the content is loaded via javascript and not part of the initial HTML? Should that be a concern at all? What's the best practice for that?

Comment: We are using `noscript` tags containing a list of the initial given content with a next and previous urls that works, of course. Hope it's enough :)

Comment: does googlebot execute ajax requests?

Comment: @James: Yes & no, but mostly no (when it comes to search results).  http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81766

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're following best practices and gracefully degrading for browsers and bots that don't use JavaScript, your page should be fine.

In the case of infinite scrolling, you should have normal HTML link elements which go to a page with the next content.  By having these links, googlebot or other web crawlers can find your additional content even if they aren't able to observe the infinite scrolling feature on the page.

Answer (score 2):

The same rules apply for infinite scrolling as for all other Ajax applications, too.

The best practice is [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) - your page should work without JavaScript, too. You are coding a serverside pagination mechanism anyway, so serve the first page of this as standard HTML output. If the client supports the needed technologies (basic JS, XHR), remove the "next page" links and load them dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

i tell you what to do
disable javascript from your browser and if you can see a link to the other page then your ok.. if you can't the you have a problem 
you will have to create a pagination and make it only shown if the javascript is disbled

Answer (score 0):

Not is true that Google don´t read JavaScript, Google read some javascript code but not all.
Ajax is not useful for SEO but some javascript is read. 
For example the typical menus with javascript if you have disable JS will not show some links of the typical cascade menu. But Google allow this type of JS, so is not true that the crawler don´t read all JS.

So if your content is loaded with Ajax, it will not be read. But if is loaded with some simple JS will be read by Google.